# Use the comparison test to determine whether the integral is convergent or divergent.

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

$\int^\infty_1 \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}} dx    $

So far I have found that $\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}} \ge \frac{1}{x^4}    $ and then since $ \frac{1}{x^4}    $ converges (known by the P-test) I know that the integral converges as well. But the answer in the textbook is that the integral diverges.

I am not sure what I am missing.
I was also wondering if there are any tricks for picking the function to compare the initial integral (in this case $ \frac{1}{x^4}    $ )?

Comment: A smaller integral converges? So what? You need to prove that a larger integral converges. You won't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}}\geq \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4}}\ge\frac{x}{x^2}=1/x.
$$
Now apply the comparison test on $[2,\infty]$. Alternatively observe that
$$
\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}}\sim\frac{1}{x}
$$
and apply the limit comparison test.

Comment: I understand that but why don't we use $ \frac{1}{x^4}    $  since its graph looks more similar to the original integral?

Comment: I am still confused on why $\frac 1/x$ is the better function to use?

Comment: You cannot deduce that the integral converges or diverges based on your inequality. You've shown that the value of the integral in question $I\geq c$ where $c<\infty$. This can imply that $I=\infty$ or $I<\infty$.

Comment: Alright and then how is your inequality different?

Comment: $\int_1^\infty 1/x\, dx=\infty$, hence $I=\infty$ where $I$ is the integral in question.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You should consider $$\int^\infty_1 \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}} dx=\int^2_1 \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}} dx+\int^\infty_2 \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}} dx$$

which diverges, indeed

$$\int^2_1 \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}} dx$$

converges but

$$\int^\infty_2 \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}} dx$$

diverges by comparison with $\frac1x$.

Answer (score 0):

A more "eye-balling" way to see it. For large $x$, you may approximate 
$$
x+1\approx x\\
\sqrt{x^4-x}\approx x^2
$$
meaning near infinity, your integral looks like
$$
\int_{M}^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{x}
$$
You can dress the above up in more rigor, and make sure it is right, but this is the intuition. Namely,
$$
\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x^3-1}}\stackrel{x+1\geq x}{\geq} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x^3-1}}\\
\stackrel{\sqrt{x^3-1}\leq \sqrt{x^3}}{\geq}\frac{1}{x}
$$
now use monotonicity of integration.
Note also, as a bonus, your integral converges at $1$. Since the numerator is bounded near $1$, it won't hurt us and we can examine
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}
$$
again ignore the bounded pieces in the product and single out the singularity
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}
$$
which is integrable near $1$ by the $p$ test.